# Parsing multiple date string languages and formats

Tags: python, string, date, parsing, internationalization

I'm parsing a list of emails in a text file and I need to parse dates in the email headers. The dates are in a multitude of formats and languages:

```
sexta-feira, 26 de agosto de 2022 16:41
viernes, 26 de agosto de 2022 19:24
2022/08/26 13:30:56
26 de agosto de 2022 13:32:49 BRT
```

Mostly portuguese, spanish, italian and english.

What would be the best aproach? I have tried `Babel` but the date parsing is very basic. For now I only have access to the text files exported from `Outlook` not the `smpt` sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package provides modules to parse localized dates in most string formats.

The following snippet successfully retrieves all dates in the given example:

```py
import dateparser

text_dates = [
    "sexta-feira, 26 de agosto de 2022 16:41",
    "viernes, 26 de agosto de 2022 19:24",
    "2022/08/26 13:30:56",
    "26 de agosto de 2022 13:32:49 BRT",
]

datetimes = [dateparser.parse(line) for line in text_dates]
```

```py
print(datetimes)

>>> [datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 26, 16, 41),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 26, 19, 24),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 26, 13, 30, 56),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 26, 13, 32, 49, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'BRT'>)]
```